# Testing string for no content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I want to send a message to a ruby string object that tests for no_content:

```
"".content? => false # same as .empty?
"   ".content? => false # same as .blank?
"\n\t".content? => false # new feature
```

Specifically, `content?` would pass true if there is anything a person could read there. I am going to monkey patch the String class to do this with a regular expression.

```
"\n\t\n\n".gsub(/[\n|\t]/,'').empty?
```

This gets me close, but I might be re-inventing the wheel and would like a more complete solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [`present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) in ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 2):

`strip` it before checking.

`"\n\t".strip.empty?`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
class String
  def content?
    self !~ /\A\s*\z/
  end
end

"".content? #=> false
"   ".content? #=> false
"\n\t".content? #=> false
"foo".content? #=> true
```

Comment: Can't you just do `!~` instead of wrapping it in parentheses and negating the entire expression?

Comment: Sure, you can, I just started from the regex that matches and then stuck the negation in front of it. Fixed now, thanks!